# Sending an axios Post request with csv in its body

Tags: reactjs

What i am trying to achieve is send a post request from my frontend to back end using axios.This post request has a csv file in its body.

Using postman : [postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6o49.png)

My code is this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'

class SessionsUpdate extends Component {
  state = {
    selectedFile: null
  }


  handleSubmit = async () => {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', this.state.selectedFile);
    await axios.post(
      'https://localhost:8765/...', 
      formData,
      { headers: { 'x-observatory-auth': localStorage.getItem("token"), 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } }
    )

    console.log("log")  //this is not printed here
  }

  onFileChange = event => {
    this.setState({ selectedFile: event.target.files[0] });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <h1>Choose a file to store</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
          <fieldset>
            <input type="file" accept=".csv" onChange={this.onFileChange} />
          </fieldset>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default SessionsUpdate;
```

So the HTML part creates a simple GUI to select a csv file from local storage and what i want is to pass this csv file to my post request.After searching online the main way i found to do this is by using formdata but it does not work on my case and i have been stuck in this for quite a while.This requests works fine on postman though.

Any ideas about what i am missing?

Comment: Can you explain why this approach is not working?

Comment: @codebling I excpect some data to be returned from the post request but i think i don't get a response from the server.The console.log in Handlesubmit is never printed.

Comment: @Epitheoritis32 are you the same user that posted the question? You should put add more explanation of what you have tried, your thesis on why it's not working. Do you get an exception in the console? Have you confirmed that the request is being sent (look in the network tab of the developer tools)?

Comment: @codebling The request to the server is pending

Comment: For some reason this worked after moving the https request in onFileChange

Comment: glad you figured it out